# Bash : Retries in a loop

Tags: bash

I have a bash script that sets up a bunch of config files and end with the block

```
sudo stop myapp
sleep 10
sudo start myapp
```

This enables me to go to `localhost:3001` and use the UI. However for some reason the app sometimes dsnt start do I want to wrap it in a loop of sort. This is what I did:

```
set -xe

restart_app () {
        sudo stop myapp
        sleep 10
        sudo start myapp
}
restart_app

for i in {1..10};
do
        status=$(curl -Is localhost:3001 | head -1 | awk '{print $2}') # returns 200
        if [ -z "$status" ];then
                restart_myapp
        else
                :
        fi
done
```

`status` returns 200 if the app is up. It returns nothing if it isnt. However my script dsnt exit at all and simply goes on for 10 tries.

Answer (score 2):

> However my script dsnt exit at all and simply goes on for 10 tries.

You need to break out of `for` loop in `else`:

```
for i in {1..10};
do
        status=$(curl -Is localhost:3001 | awk 'NR==1{print $2; exit}')
        if [[ -z "$status" ]];then
                restart_myapp
        else
                break
        fi
done
```

Also `head` is unnecessary here since `awk` can have condition `NR==1` for first record.

Comment: I did have break until I came across a SO answer that said break is similar to `:`. Anyways even after adding in the break the script runs for all 10 tries....

Comment: Last comment before going offline, add `declare -p status` before if condition and check value.

Comment: `declare -- status=""`

Comment: Try adding a small sleep after the restart step - I have a feeling your app is not warmed up when you curl and hence it is not returning a 200, forcing you to restart yet again, and that goes on in each iteration.

Comment: Right after start what is output of `curl -Is localhost:3001`? Most likely your app is taking long time to start. As @codeforester rightly suggests, put a `sleep 5` (5 seconds delay) before `curl` command.